# SQLite Datetime before 24 hours query

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, datetime, fmdb

I have a database table and storing a datetime column with the UTC datetime, iOS [NSDate date] is returning always a UTC datetime. It's all good about it.

I'm using FMDB to get the last 12 and 24 hours data with the following code.

```
[self.fmQueue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db)
   {
   NSString* queryCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@ WHERE %@ >= Datetime('?')", readingsTable, dateTimeRecordedColumn];
   NSDate* dateBefore24Hours = [self.dateUtilities dateBySubtractingDays:1 forDate:[NSDate date]];
   WEELogDebug(@"Date before 24 hours: %@", dateBefore24Hours);
   FMResultSet* result = [db executeQuery:queryCommand, dateBefore24Hours];
   if (completionblock)
      {
      completionblock([self readingsArrayFromResultSet:result]);
      }
   }];
```

What I need to accomplish is retrieve all data that has a date after the `dateBefore24Hours` variable. The debug message shows the correct value, for example [NSDate date] now before 24 hours is, `Date before 24 hours: 2015-04-06 15:28:08 +0000`, so I should get al the records until `2015-04-07 15:28:08 +0000` with the above query, but I don't.

With SQLite Studio I provide you with the records I have at the moment in the database.

[image: Records in SQLite]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the `Datetime()` function. (And even if you did, one would never put the `?` within quotation marks.)

When FMDB encounters a `NSDate` object in the list of parameters, it will automatically do `timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT` (if you didn't specify a `dateFormat` string), and so this numeric representation of the date can be used when comparing to your `dateTimeRecorded` column. By the way, this numeric value can be accessed in SQLite as a `unixepoch` value.

Bottom line, you should simply be able to use `?`:

```
SELECT * FROM %@ WHERE %@ >= ?
```

Comment: Yes, it works, this is a result of copy paste and not having in mind that I don't work with string datetime representation which I would need the DATETIME() function of SQLite. Thanks it works.